# Laravel Mix not immediately exiting/terminating after compiled success

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a project that is currently using Laravel Jetstream with Inertia (inertia-vue2). While at first, it was good, but now I have irritated issue that also affects my GitHub actions. When I run, say, `yarn dev` or `yarn prod`, then it compiled successfully, it didn't exit immediately unless I press `ctrl+c` then terminate it. It was fine that I need to do that every time I run `yarn dev` on my machine (but honestly, I'm not), but this has become the problem on GitHub actions because I can't manually terminate Laravel Mix on the workflow. I was waiting to finish the build step for 3 hours to terminate itself, but it didn't. Any way to fix this? Here's the screenshot and my `webpack.mix.js` and my `webpack.config.js`.

This is the 8th time I have run this job, still the same result. Modify the `webpack.mix.js`, remove the yarn.lock and node_modules on my machine, then push the yarn.lock, still same, I'm running out of ideas.

[image]

And here's my webpack.mix.js (and yes, I have PostCSS and SASS, I was intending to going full sass, but since Vuetify is struggling, so at the moment, I'll use the postcss instead for Vuetify stuff, but other than that, I'm using sass)

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-favicon');
require('vuetifyjs-mix-extension');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ])
    .sass('resources/sass/print.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'))
    .vuetify()
    .sourceMaps()
    .favicon({
        blade: 'resources/views/favicon.blade.php',
    })
    .disableNotifications();

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

And here's my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
        },
    },
    output: {
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]',
    }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[EDIT]
In Github Actions, I always cancel workflow, and I don't want to wait for three hours++ anymore. This is a pain T-T.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried by hitting Enter button, as some times console commands get stucked due to poor system performance.

Comment: @sohailamar I tried, didn't do anything unless I `ctrl+c` (force terminate) it. Also, I don't know how to do that in GitHub Actions.

Comment: Please add your package.json.

Comment: I fixed it! laravel-mix-favicon did this. I remove it from webpack.mix.js and now the pain is gone. Idk what the package is doing but it work after remove it. Sorry about this stupid question 